# Calling variables in private method Java Libgdx

Tags: java, variables, libgdx

I am trying to call a variable from a private method into another method in the same class, but on `chicken.x` i get the error:

```
chicken cannot be resolved to a variable
```

How can I call the sprite rectangle out of the private method?

**Code:**

```
public class OptionScreen implements Screen{
    ...
    Array<Rectangle> chickens;
    ...

    public OptionsScreen(){
        ...
        chickens = new Array<Rectangle>();
        ...
    }

    private void spawnChicken(){
        Rectangle chicken = new Rectangle();
        ...
        chickens.add(chicken);
        ...
    }

    public void render(float delta){
        ...
        diffYchick = (float) (farmerY - chicken.y); // Error here
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: What class is `method` in and what class is `render` in?

Comment: @Andrew_CS both in same OptionScreen class, chicken is the actual name for the sprite

Comment: Still not sure what you mean with `chicken`.  I've updated my answer.   Are you trying to call `render` in the `main` method of the `OptionScreen` class?

Comment: @Andrew_CS sprite takes the place of chicken in my game

Comment: You need to show the code that contains `chicken` if neither answer here has solved your issue.

Comment: @Andrew_CS   diffXchick = (float) (farmerX - chicken.x);

Comment: What is the type of `chicken`?  Where are you initializing it?  I tried to chat with you to fix your problem but you didn't respond.  You're making it difficult for people to help you.

Comment: @Andrew_CS 1st how do i use the chat?  here is some more info Array<Rectangle> chickens;
chickens = new Array<Rectangle>();            pls c http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24763379/controlling-and-creating-multiple-sprites-array-java-libgdx?noredirect=1#comment38425579_24763379             another  question which should provide more info

Comment: Follow this link to chat - http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57343/discussion-between-andrew-cs-and-user3165683

Comment: @Andrew_CS pls c edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**After Chat** To answer the underlying problem that was discussed in chat:

There was an `ArrayList<Rectangle> chickens` as an instance variable for the `OptionsScreen` class.  The OP wasn't getting the `Rectangle`'s out of the `ArrayList` in the `render` method.  OP was using a variable name `chicken` from a different method, `spawnChicken` that only had method scope.  I showed the OP how to loop over the `ArrayList` in the `render` method, access the `Rectangle`s one at a time, and then perform the necessary operations.

---

**From Before Chat And Edited Question** The scope of `sprite` is only in the method `method`.  This means that you can only make use of the `sprite` variable while inside of `method`.  You could make `sprite` an instance variable, then you could access it in another method of that same class.

```
public class OptionScreen{
    private Rectangle sprite; // Make instance variable

    public OptionScreen(){ // Constructor - called when initializing
        sprite = new Rectangle(); // Initialize (so it's not null)
        ... // Set other info on sprite, such as x
    }

    public void render(float delta){
        ...
        sprite.x;
        ...
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){ // Example of useage
        OptionScreen optionScreen = new OptionScreen(); // Constructor called
        optionScreen.render(1.1);
    }
}
```

Initializing `sprite` in a constructor ensures that it won't be `null` when attempting to use `render`.  (Unless you set it to `null`)

---

*Note:* It is probably a good idea to not name methods `method` since it gets confusing.

Answer (score 0):

If you define `sprite` locally in one method, you cannot access it within another method.

Not sure about the `chicken` though (there is no such variable in the code you posted).

If `sprite` must be accessed by a different method, make it an instance variable.

```
public class ClassName 
{
  private Rectangle _sprite = null;

  ...

  private void method(){
     _sprite = new Rectangle();
  }

  ...

  public void render(float delta) {
    if (_sprite != null) {
      _sprite.x ...
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: IS THERE NO WAY? WHAT WOULD U RECOMMEND I DO INSTEAD?

Comment: @user3165683 If you need this instance to live beyond the scope of the method where you define it, make it an instance variable.

Comment: i then get the error Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.NullPointerException on sprite.x etc???

Comment: @user3165683 You must initialize the sprite class before accessing its members.

Comment: how would u initialse the class?

Comment: @user3165683 I meant initialize the sprite variable. You initialize it in the method you called `method`, so you should call `method` before calling `render`.